# Using FileProvider to open PDF included in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I have included two PDFs that I want to open from my app. They should open with whatever PDF viewer the user has installed. I placed the PDFs in /res/raw. I used this code:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getPath(), s);
            Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

My filepaths.xml looks like this:

```
<paths>
<files-path path="raw/" name="raw" />
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.dsv2019.pvt15.prepapp/files/hjartlugnraddning.pdf
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems.

First, `<files-path path="raw/" name="raw" />` says that it serves files from a `raw/` subdirectory under `getFilesDir()`. However, `new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getPath(), s)` will not have such a directory, unless it is in `s` somehow, and the error suggests that it is not. BTW, you can simplify this as `new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), s)`.

Second, I think that you are assuming the existence of a `raw/` directory in `getFilesDir()`. Unless you create that directory, it will not exist.

Third, I think that you are thinking that raw resources are files on the device. They are not. They are files on your development machine. They are just entries in the APK file on the device.

So, to make this work, you need to add code to:

- Create a `raw/` subdirectory off of `getFilesDir()`
- Use `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object to copy the resource to a file in that newly-created `raw/` subdirectory
- Use that `File` object from the preceding step with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`

Comment: Thank you. Where is the correct place to store my PDF files, if not in res/raw? Also, is there a tutorial available that goes through the steps you mentioned? I've googled a lot but never managed to find one.

Comment: @Rattletrap: "Where is the correct place to store my PDF files, if not in res/raw?" -- if you want to package a PDF with your app, `res/raw/` or `assets/` are fine. However, neither of those locations magically unpack to files on the device. In both cases, you need to copy the bytes to a file. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android) shows the process, using `assets/` for the PDF instead of a raw resource.

Comment: It works now. Thank you SO much. Have a great weekend!